# How to overcome grub rescue?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, grub, linux-mint

I had windows 7 installed, I had installed linux mint. I freed up one of my partitions from windows drive management to remove linux and now when I load, the screen I get is error: filesystem not found.
grub rescue prompt.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't think it is a duplicate

Comment: There are about 200 other duplicates to choose from. Did you actually try it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you remove/format partition where where Linux Mint is installed?....

If you need only Windows then Follow these steps:

1. Boot From the Windows Install Disc
2. Just click on "Repair your computer"
3. Select First option "Use Recovery tool that can......"
4. then Chose Command Prompt.
5. After This type those Commands `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot`

After a reboot your Windows system should be working fine.